# How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I want to initialize a struct element, split in declaration and initialization. This is what I have:

```
typedef struct MY_TYPE {
  bool flag;
  short int value;
  double stuff;
} MY_TYPE;

void function(void) {
  MY_TYPE a;
  ...
  a = { true, 15, 0.123 }
}
```

Is this the way to declare and initialize a local variable of `MY_TYPE` in accordance with C programming language standards (C89, C90, C99, C11, etc.)? Or is there anything better or at least working?

**Update** I ended up having a static initialization element where I set every subelement according to my needs.

Comment: you really should accept a better answer, I see you had to use some bad coding guide, but you still shouldn't suggest to other people that that is the right way to do it..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath well, most of the good answers are specific to C99. Maybe my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624975/c90-how-do-i-globally-initialize-this-struct-in-c-without-c99-extensions ?

Comment: if that was your original intention, then probably yes, but then 1) the votes would be very misleading. 2) from the top search hits this is the only one which shows the C99 way..... it would be better to re-use this page for C99 demonstration... (apparently people started to link this page to show how to do it)

Comment: Interesting that the accepted (and heavily upvoted) answer doesn't actually answer the question, even as originally posted. Designated initializers don't address the OP's problem, which is to *split* the declaration from the initialization. For pre-1999 C, the only real solution is to assign to each member; for C99 and later, a compound literal, as in CesarB's answer, is the solution. (Of course an actual initializer, with or without designators, would be even better, but apparently the OP was saddled with a really bad coding standard.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the term "ANSI C" now refers to the 2011 ISO standard, which ANSI has adopted. But in practice the term "ANSI C" commonly refers to the (officially obsolete) 1989 standard. For example, "gcc -ansi" still enforces the 1989 standard. Since it's ISO that published the 1990, 1999, and 2011 standards, it's best to avoid the term "ANSI C", and to refer to the date of the standard if there's any possibility of confusion.

Comment: See also [Designated initializers and omitted elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763763/designated-initializers-and-omitted-elements) for another aspect of the use of designated initializers.  It isn't a duplicate of this question; it does provide useful extra information.

Answer (score 991, accepted):

In C99, you can use a **designated initializer** to initialize a structure:

```
MY_TYPE a = { .flag = true, .value = 123, .stuff = 0.456 };
```

Other members are initialized as zero: "Omitted field members are implicitly initialized the same as objects that have static storage duration." (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

Comment: awesome, thanks.
you can even nest em:
static oxeRay2f ray = { .unitDir = { .x = 1.0f, .y = 0.0f } };

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. OP wants to separate the initialization from the declaration.

Comment: C99 != ANSI C - 
So this doesn't work in C89, nor in C90.

Comment: C99 **is** ANSI C, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206568/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c99-ansi-c-and-gnu-c)

Comment: @CutbertoOcampo your comment is not clear, the link you point to states that ANSI C is C89. It even states "Please note that since 1989, ANSI haven't had anything to do with the C language. Programmers still speaking about "ANSI C" generally haven't got a clue about what it means. ISO "owns" the C language, through the standard ISO 9899."

Comment: @Étienne, agreed, technically they're not the same. However, in terms of what was being discussed by @ twity1337 (i.e. versions/standardization) I stand by my comment

Comment: @CutbertoOcampo I understand what happened now. The original question was asking for solutions in ANSI C, obviously he wanted answers for C89 only. In 2016 the question was edited and "ANSI C" was removed, which now makes it hard to understand why this answer and comments mention "(ANSI) C99".

Comment: An odd "gotcha" I ran into is that if you don't initialize every field of everything, the compiler would call `memset` to zero the other fields. In the interest of a minimal-size executable I was building without the CRT, had no `memset`, my code wouldn't link, and it took me a while to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Beware, if you try this C89 or C90 you will get a nasty `error: expected an expression`

Answer (score 269):

You can do it with a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). According to that page, it works in C99 (which also counts as [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C)).

```
MY_TYPE a;

a = (MY_TYPE) { .flag = true, .value = 123, .stuff = 0.456 };
...
a = (MY_TYPE) { .value = 234, .stuff = 1.234, .flag = false };
```

The designations in the initializers are optional; you could also write:

```
a = (MY_TYPE) { true,  123, 0.456 };
...
a = (MY_TYPE) { false, 234, 1.234 };
```

Comment: So, designated initializers are for when you declare and define at the same time, but compound literals are for when you define an already-declared variable?

Comment: @Geremia you have to first define the struct in both cases, but with designated initializers, you make the code more readable, and more resilient to errors, in case of changes in the struct.

Comment: This is a little tricky. Many times (some successful) I have tried to use designated initializers. However, it only has now become clear (thanks to your and @philant's example) that there must exist a cast if the initializer is not used at the time of object creation. However, I have now also learned that if initializers are used at a time other than object creation (as in your example) then it is referred to as a **compound literal**, not strictly a **designated initializer**. https://ideone.com/Ze3rnZ

Comment: Just as a clarification on the comment from @sherrellbc above, if "initializers are used at a time other than object creation" then they are *not initializers*.  Initialization takes place at the same time as definition; any value change at another time is assignment, not initialization.  So a designated initializer can be used only for initialization, whereas a compound literal can only be used for assignment.  The syntax is slightly different as well because the compound literal always requires a cast.

Comment: The difference between initialization and assignment is important in the context of `const` (where assignment is not possible but initialization is) and `static` (static locals are initialized only once, at the time of creation).

Answer (score 116):

I see you've already received an answer about ANSI C 99, so I'll throw a bone about ANSI C 89.
ANSI C 89 allows you to initialize a struct this way:

```
typedef struct Item {
    int a;
    float b;
    char* name;
} Item;

int main(void) {
    Item item = { 5, 2.2, "George" };
    return 0;
}
```

An important thing to remember, at the moment you initialize even one object/ variable in the struct, all of its other variables will be initialized to default value.

If you don't initialize the values in your struct, all variables will contain "garbage values".

Comment: Is it possible to use variables in the initialization ?

Comment: @Cyan It is for objects with automatic storage duration. See 6.7.9 13) in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf . For global objects is pretty much restricted to literals. You can't even use other global objects, even if they're const.

Comment: So the only difference with C 99 is that you can't specify the designations?

Answer (score 51):

`a = (MYTYPE){ true, 15, 0.123 };`

would do fine in C99

Answer (score 25):

C programming language standard **ISO/IEC 9899:1999** (commonly known as C99) allows one to use a **designated initializer** to initialize members of a structure or union as follows:

```
MY_TYPE a = { .stuff = 0.456, .flag = true, .value = 123 };
```

It is defined in `paragraph 7`, section `6.7.8 Initialization` of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard as:

> If a designator has the form
>   . identifier
>   then the current object (defined below) shall have structure or union type and the identifier shall be the name of a member of that type.

Note that `paragraph 9` of the same section states that:

> Except where explicitly stated otherwise, for the purposes of this subclause unnamed members of objects of structure and union type do not participate in initialization. **Unnamed members of structure objects have indeterminate value even after initialization.**

In GNU GCC implementation however omitted members are initialized as zero or zero-like type-appropriate value. As stated in section [6.27 Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) of GNU GCC documentation:

> Omitted field members are implicitly initialized the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Microsoft Visual C++ compiler should support designated initializers since version 2013 according to official blog post [C++ Conformance Roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/somasegar/2013/06/28/c-conformance-roadmap/). Paragraph `Initializing unions and structs` of [Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177(v=vs.140).aspx)  article at MSDN Visual Studio documentation suggests that unnamed members initialized to zero-like appropriate values similarly to GNU GCC.

**ISO/IEC 9899:2011** standard (commonly known as C11) which had superseded ISO/IEC 9899:1999 retains designated initializers under section `6.7.9 Initialization`. It also retains `paragraph 9` unchanged.

New **ISO/IEC 9899:2018** standard (commonly known as C18) which had superseded ISO/IEC 9899:2011 retains designated initializers under section `6.7.9 Initialization`. It also retains `paragraph 9` unchanged.

Comment: I believe "Unnamed member" doesn't mean "omitted fields", but rather "anonymous members" such as the union in `struct thing { union { char ch; int i; }; };`. The standard later says: "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there  are  elements  in  the  array,the  remainder  of  the  aggregate  shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Answer (score 25):

Adding to All of these good answer a summary to how to initialize a structure (union and Array) in C, focused especially on the Designed Initializer.

### Standard Initialization

```c
struct point 
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}

p = {1.2, 1.3};
```

---

### Designated Initializer

The Designated Initializer came up since the ISO C99 and is a different and more dynamic way to initialize in C when initializing `struct`, `union` or an `array`.

The biggest difference to standard initialization is that you don't have to declare the elements in a fixed order and you can also omit element.

From The [GNU Guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

> Standard C90 requires the elements of an initializer to appear in a fixed order, the same as the order of the elements in the array or structure being initialized.

> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in random order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well

---

### Examples

#### 1. Array Index

**Standard Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = {[4] = 29, [2] = 15 }; // or
int a[6] = {[4]29 , [2]15 }; // or
int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
```

#### 2. Struct or union:

**Standard Initialization**

```c
struct point { int x, y; };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
struct point p = { .y = 2, .x = 3 }; or
struct point p = { y: 2, x: 3 };
```

#### 3. Combine naming elements with ordinary C initialization of successive elements:

**Standard Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = { 0, v1, v2, 0, v4, 0 };
```

**Designated Initialization**

```c
int a[6] = { [1] = v1, v2, [4] = v4 };
```

#### 4. Others:

**Labeling the elements of an array initializer**

```c
int whitespace[256] = { [' '] = 1, ['\t'] = 1, ['\h'] = 1,
                        ['\f'] = 1, ['\n'] = 1, ['\r'] = 1 };
```

**write a series of ‘.fieldname’ and ‘[index]’ designators before an ‘=’ to specify a nested subobject to initialize**

```c
struct point ptarray[10] = { [2].y = yv2, [2].x = xv2, [0].x = xv0 };
```

---

### Guides

- [designated-initializers-c | geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designated-initializers-c/)
- [using-designated-initializers](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/18609/using-designated-initializers)
- [tutorialspoint.com | designated-initializers-in-c](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/designated-initializers-in-c)

Comment: `struct point { int x, y; };` under **2. Struct or union** titled with *Standard Initialization* is not an initialization. It is the definition of the type `struct point`. There is not even memory allocated yet. With the code titled "*Designated Initialization*" a variable of type `struct point` is then declared (as `p`) and initialized (with p.y = 2, p.x = 3) at once. After that we have allocated and initialized memory plus a name (`p`) for this bit of memory.

Comment: The code titled "*Labeling the elements of an array*" does not "label" elements, it picks elements to initialize (which is stated correctly below the code). If you want, the elements are already labelled with `int whitespace[256];`. There are now 256 elements labelled with 0, 1, 2, ..., 255. It just so happens that the characters `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\h'`, ... (of type `char`) are implicitly casted to `int` where they would be written as 32, 9, 92, 104, 12, 10, 13. So there are 7 elements picked of the 256 which are initialized with `1`, the other 249 elements are implicitly initialized with `0`.

Answer (score 24):

You've almost got it...

```
MY_TYPE a = { true, 15, 0.123 };
```

Quick [search on 'struct initialize c'](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=struct+initialize+c) [shows me this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html)

Comment: I think this is true for standard C, but not for ANSI C(99?).

Also I'm bound to coding rules that won't allow me to do declaration and initialization at once, so I have to split it up and initialize every single subelement.

Comment: Initialization can only happen at the point of declaration.  That is what it means to 'initialize'.  Otherwise you're allowing an undefined value to be the inital value of your variable / struct, and then assigning a value later.

Comment: um... You have coding rules that are deliberately bad?  Perhaps you should introduce the guy who wrote them to "Resource Acquisition Is Initialization" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)

Comment: Trust me, I really, really, can't change a bit of this rules at this point. It feels horrible to code it. And there are a lot of other rules right out of the 70s, like static code headers with management information like Revision number. Changes for every release, even if the source didn't change...

Answer (score 17):

as [Ron Nuni said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006240/4298200):

```
typedef struct Item {
    int a;
    float b;
    char* name;
} Item;

int main(void) {
    Item item = {5, 2.2, "George"};
    return 0;
}
```

An important thing to remember: at the moment you initialize even one object/variable in the struct, all of its other variables will be initialized to default value.

If you don't initialize the values in your struct (i.e. if you just declare that variable), all `variable.members` will contain "garbage values", **only if the declaration is local!**

If the declaration is **global or static** (like in this case), all uninitialized **`variable.members`** will be initialized automatically to:

- `0` for integers and floating point
- `'\0'` for `char` (of course this is just the same as `0`, and `char` is an integer type)
- `NULL` for pointers.

Comment: Interesting about the local/global, this also applies to struct tm time values.  I had a local one and in one case DST was on, in another it wasn't, not due to anything I did.  I wasn't using DST (the tm_isdst field), this was from strptime, but when I converted to time_t some were an hour off.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't like any of these answers so I made my own.  I don't know if this is ANSI C or not, it's just GCC 4.2.1 in it's default mode.  I never can remember the bracketing so I start with a subset of my data and do battle with compiler error messages until it shuts up.  Readability is my first priority.

```
// in a header:
typedef unsigned char uchar;

struct fields {
  uchar num;
  uchar lbl[35];
};

// in an actual c file (I have 2 in this case)
struct fields labels[] = {
  {0, "Package"},
  {1, "Version"},
  {2, "Apport"},
  {3, "Architecture"},
  {4, "Bugs"},
  {5, "Description-md5"},
  {6, "Essential"},
  {7, "Filename"},
  {8, "Ghc-Package"},
  {9, "Gstreamer-Version"},
  {10, "Homepage"},
  {11, "Installed-Size"},
  {12, "MD5sum"},
  {13, "Maintainer"},
  {14, "Modaliases"},
  {15, "Multi-Arch"},
  {16, "Npp-Description"},
  {17, "Npp-File"},
  {18, "Npp-Name"},
  {19, "Origin"}
};
```

The data may start life as a tab-delimited file that you search-replace to massage into something else.  Yes, this is Debian stuff.  So one outside pair of {} (indicating the array), then another pair for each struct inside.  With commas between.  Putting things in a header isn't strictly necessary, but I've got about 50 items in my struct so I want them in a separate file, both to keep the mess out of my code and so it's easier to replace.

Comment: There were no question about initialization of array of structures! I mean, your answer contains overhead.

Comment: I guess my point was declaring the struct with values already in it vs. using = to set each value later.

Comment: That principle applies whether it's one struct or an array of them.  Using = isn't really initialization, I wouldn't think.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in different ways:

```
MY_TYPE a = { true, 1, 0.1 };

MY_TYPE a = { .stuff = 0.1, .flag = true, .value = 1 }; //designated initializer, not available in c++

MY_TYPE a;
a = (MY_TYPE) { true,  1, 0.1 };

MY_TYPE m (true, 1, 0.1); //works in C++, not available in C
```

Also, you can define member while declaring structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MY_TYPE
{
    int a;
    int b;
}m = {5,6};

int main()
{
    printf("%d  %d\n",m.a,m.b);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```C
void function(void) {
  MY_TYPE a;
  a.flag = true;
  a.value = 15;
  a.stuff = 0.123;
}
```

Comment: once i've heard 'initialization is different than assignment'. so isn't this an assignment rather than initialization?

Answer (score 3):

If MS has not updated to C99, `MY_TYPE a = { true,15,0.123 };`

Answer (score 3):

I found another way to initialize structs.

The struct:

```
typedef struct test {
    int num;
    char* str;
} test;
```

Initialization:

```
test tt = {
    num: 42,
    str: "nice"
};
```

As per GCC’s documentation, this syntax is [obsolete since GCC 2.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Answer (score 1):

Structure in C can be declared and initialized like this:

```
typedef struct book
{
    char title[10];
    char author[10];
    float price;
} book;

int main() {
    book b1={"DS", "Ajay", 250.0};

    printf("%s \t %s \t %f", b1.title, b1.author, b1.price);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Documentation for Initializing Aggregate Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k8cwsz.aspx) yet, all forms of initializing with `{...}` are explained there, but the initializing with dot, named ''designator'' isn't mentioned there. It does not work also.

The C99 standard chapter 6.7.8 Initialization explains the possibility of designators, but in my mind it is not really clear for complex structs. The [C99 standard as pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) .

In my mind, it may be better to

1. Use the `= {0};`-initialization for all static data. It is less effort for the machine code.
2. Use macros for initializing, for example

   `typedef MyStruct_t{ int x, int a, int b; } MyStruct;
   define INIT_MyStruct(A,B) { 0, A, B}`

The macro can be adapted, its argument list can be independent of changed struct content. It is proper if less elements should be initialized. It is also proper for nested struct.
3. A simple form is: Initialize in a subroutine:

```
void init_MyStruct(MyStruct* thiz, int a, int b) {
  thiz->a = a; thiz->b = b; }
```

This routine looks like ObjectOriented in C. Use `thiz`, not `this` to compile it with C++ too!

```
MyStruct data = {0}; //all is zero!
init_MyStruct(&data, 3, 456);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cool way to initialize `structure` members in C is to use the colon syntax. The following is how you can do it.

```
MY_TYPE a = {flag:true, value:123, stuff:0.456};
```

Answer (score -3):

I've been looking for a nice way to initialize my struct, and I've got to using the below (C99). This lets me initialize either a single structure or an array of structures in the same way as plain types.

```
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    size_t len;
    jsmntok_t *tok;
    int tsz;
} jsmn_ts;

#define jsmn_ts_default (jsmn_ts){NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
```

This can be used in the code as:

```
jsmn_ts mydata = jsmn_ts_default; /* initialization of a single struct */

jsmn_ts myarray[10] = {jsmn_ts_default, jsmn_ts_default}; /* initialization of
                                                    first 2 structs in the array */
```

Comment: But this does not initialize an array of structures to the default values. It initializes the first structure in the array to the values given in `jsmn_ts_default`, but the rest of the structures are initialized as if the array had static storage duration, which means that the members are initialized to `NULL` and `0`. But if you change to `#define jsmn_ts_default (jsmn_ts){"default", sizeof "default", NULL, 0}` you will see that only the first array element gets so initialized.

Comment: Yes, I just came back from more testing, wanted to edit the post :) btw, same behaviour happens with `int a[10] = {1};` Only the 1st element will be `==1`