# Strange structure definition

Tags: c

In code example of Intel DPDK i have found this strange syntactical construction. Can anybody explain me what does it mean?

```
static const struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = {
    .rxmode = {
        .split_hdr_size = 0,
        .header_split   = 0,
        .hw_ip_checksum = 0,
        .hw_vlan_filter = 0,
        .jumbo_frame    = 0,
        .hw_strip_crc   = 0,
    },
    .txmode = {
    }
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763763/designated-initializers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
struct X
{
    type_a var_a;
    type_b var_b;
    type_c var_c;
    type_d var_d;
};
```

you can initialize an object like this:

```
struct X x = {value_a, value_b, value_c, value_d};
```

But this means you need to know the order of variables in `X` as well as having an initial value for all of it. Alternatively, you can initialize like this:

```
struct X x = {
    .var_a = value_a,
    .var_b = value_b,
    .var_c = value_c,
    .var_d = value_d
};
```

This way, you can initialize member variables in any order, or even skip some.

This is specially useful in a library where you have some variables needed to be initialized by the user, while other variables are more internal and could even be changed with different versions of your library. Using this kind of initialization, the user doesn't need to know about those extra variables.

Answer (score 6):

It's a C99 syntax known as a [designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

In earlier C standards, the elements of a struct initializer had to appear in the same order as in the struct definition. With designated initializers, that restriction is lifted. Naturally the struct members have to be named to indicate which member is being initialized.

Designated initializers can also be used with arrays and allow you to initialize specific elements of an array. For example:

```
int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

Answer (score 2):

This is C99 feature called [*designated initializers*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/designators.htm). It lets you specify the names of the fields to which you set values, rather than specifying the values in the order the corresponding fields appear in the declaration. Additionally, this syntax lets you initialize members of unions other than the first one - something that was impossible before C99.