# C90: How do I globally initialize this struct in C without C99 extensions

Tags: c, struct, global, declare, c89

I was wondering what the best way to initialize this struct is with C90, while still keeping it neat.

In my header file, call it test.h, I have the following struct defined:

```
 struct s_test_cfg{
      char *a[3];
      char *b[3];
      char *c[3];
 }
```

Then I have it declared as an extern struct so that I can initialize it globally in the .c file:

```
 extern struct s_test_cfg test_cfg;
```

Now in my .c file, I want to be able to declare something like this globally (obviously what I'm about to write is unsupported in C90):

```
 struct s_test_cfg test_cfg =
 { .a = {"a", "b", "c"},\
   .b = {"d", "e", "f"},\
   .c = {"g", "h", "i"} };
```

This obviously makes it very neat and transparent as to what you're trying to do. How can I initialize the global struct in my C file that is also as clean as this syntax? Thanks.

Comment: GCC but we want to keep it C90 since everything else in the project is written for C90 compatibility.

Comment: In our project we are shifting even to gcc-only extensions (some are only in gcc >= 4.5), because the probability of using another compiler is very low.

Comment: Note: there's no need for the `\\` continuation character in your initialization (unless it's actually part of a macro that spans multiple lines).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct s_test_cfg test_cfg = {
    { "a", "b", "c" },  /* .a */
    { "d", "e", "f" },  /* .b */
    { "g", "h", "i" },  /* .c */
};
```

is probably the cleanest option (short of getting yourself a C99 compiler; GCC and Intel C both support C99).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this before multiple times and got compiler errors about braces around scalar initializers, but it seems to work now for whatever reason, go figure. Thank you for confirming that this would work.