# What is the purpose of void *array = *(void **) member + siz * (*p_n);

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, c99, c89

I am trying to get a [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) example compiled with a C90 compiler (MS VS2012).

Within the protobuf-c source code there are two C99 specific things that can easily be changed to be compatible with C90, i.e. variable declaration in the middle of a scope ([not allowed in C90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513604/declare-c89-local-variables-in-the-beginning-of-the-scope)) and [instantiation of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624975/c90-how-do-i-globally-initialize-this-struct-in-c-without-c99-extensions) via the `.`-syntax (e.g. `some_struct_type name = {.a=1,.b=2}`).

I am now stuck with one compile error left. The respective line in source file 'protobuf-c.c' reads:

```
void *array = *(void **) member + siz * (*p_n);
```

Where `member` is define as `void *` and `p_n` as `size_t *`.
And the respective error is

```
error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
```

Please note this is valid for protobuf-c version 1.0.1 (see the [respective source code](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/blob/108635a35ffb2fa233797412e145b876dc0d6f82/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.c), at line 2404). This line has been changed in version 1.0.2 to

```
void *array = *(char **) member + siz * (*p_n);
```

with [this comment](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/commit/6d275c569155b00d5c8fe208f25f6c15da632d12). 
Changing the line accordingly eliminates the compilation error.

My questions are:

- I would like to understand this line of code.
- Can I switch to the `*(char **)` version?
- What is the error message telling me?

(For some other reason I want to stick to protobuf-c 1.0.1)

Comment: Looks like it's designed to be unreadable by humans. :)

Comment: There are some compilers that treat void* similar to BYTE*, at least in pointer arithmetic. i.e. sizeof(void*) compiles to 1. I would split this clutter line in it's elements and replace `void*` by `char*` *for this specific purpose of pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: @harper what would the code read if it was "de-cluttered"

Comment: A good execise would be for you to take the `char` version of it and define the same computation with temporary variables, one after another. The `void*` version is just gcc'ish garbage. `void*` arithmetic is an extension that makes not much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

parameter passed as `member` is an address of a pointer to char pointer . First the cast and defererence get that pointer.( The address of the pointer is passed so that the pointer can be changed in the function. )

The addition `siz * (*p_n)` increments the pointer to the correct element.

The whole line could be rewritten as:

```
char** pm = member ;
char* m = *pm ;
void *array = m + siz * (*p_n);
```

A change from void* to char* is made so that pointer arithmetic is possible, as C Standard doesn't allow it on void pointers. The error message is telling you that, size of the object void* is pointing to is not known, there for you have to use a char* pointer.

As long as the object passed to the function has the type `char**` you can switch to char** version.

Answer (score 2):

`I would like to understand this line of code.`

The code makes pointer arithmetic and tries to hide the details. Therefore it uses `void` everywhere the pointer is not deferenced. The assumption is that the `sizeof (*(void*))` is equal to one.

`Can I switch to the *(char **) version?`

Yes, because the code assigns the resulting pointer and don't dereferences the pointer.

`What is the error message telling me?`

This hack is compiler specific. Your compiler doesn't undestands this, it does not provide a size of a `void*` target.

You should use a "portable" version. The `sizeof(char)` is one for most compilers and for these compilers it is portable.