# What is the use of "." prefix for a structure variable in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does dot (.) mean in a struct initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047261/what-does-dot-mean-in-a-struct-initializer)

I have the following structure in which the variables are prefixed with ".". Please kindly help me understand the significance of "."

```
static struct usb_driver skel_driver = {
    .name = "skeleton",
    .probe = skel_probe,
    .disconnect = skel_disconnect,
    .fops = &skel_fops,
    .minor = USB_SKEL_MINOR_BASE,
    .id_table = skel_table,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) in GCC parlance.