# Structure of #define Macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I found this arcane construct inside include/linux/wait.h

```
 #define DEFINE_WAIT_FUNC(name, function)                                \
        wait_queue_t name = {                                            \
                 .private        = current,                              \
                 .func           = function,                             \
                 .task_list      = LIST_HEAD_INIT((name).task_list),     \
        }
```

I know good amount on macros and preproc directives in general, but I am absolutely lost on this one. Can someone please explain the above code ***structure*** in detail including the '\' at the end of the line. Thanks.

Note: I dont need to know what it does in linux, only the syntactic meaning behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` character in a macros is a line continuation character.  It simply allows the macro to span multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it. What about the rest. Its very imp for me to understand the wait_queue_t name = { .private = current,.....} part inside the body of #define?

Comment: @AnupSaumithri That doesn't have to do with macros, but is C99 syntax. [What does dot (.) mean in a struct initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047261/what-does-dot-mean-in-a-struct-initializer)

Answer (score 1):

The macro (presumably) is asociating an structure with a function pointer and doing common initialization. Lest say you want to add those structures to a list and then (during an execution step) call different functions. 
A better question would at least include wait_queue_t definition.

Answer (score 1):

As per others ([and many references on-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419530/multi-line-preprocessor-macros)), the `\` character continues any line via the c-preprocessor.  As for the rest,

> #define DEFINE_WAIT_FUNC(name, function)                               \

Definition of the macro.

> ```
>    wait_queue_t name = {                                            \
> ```

Declares a `wait_queue_t` with the macro substitution *name*.

> ```
>             .private        = current,                              \
> ```

Initialize the `private` wait_queue_t structure member with the `current` task pointer.  This is also a macro (perhaps inline assembler) defined by each architecture in the Linux tree.

> ```
>             .func           = function,                             \
> ```

Set the `func` member to the *function* parameter.

> ```
>             .task_list      = LIST_HEAD_INIT((name).task_list),     \
> ```

Initializes the list as empty.  `task_list` points to itself.

The `.` notation is used through-out the kernel source and is a *gcc* feature (and later C99), called [*designated intializers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).  Instead of having to set **all** members of a structure, only the named ones are initialized with the others set to zero.  This allows people to extend the structure without modifying all the declarations.  It is not a *c-preprocessor* feature, but a 'C' language (extension).