# Converting code from c to c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to convert some code from C to C++
This is a project using a raspberry pi with camera module and I'd like to analyse pictures with it.

But on this piece of code (somebody else created) I get this error

```
231:8: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

Which is this line:

```
.max_stills_w = state->width,
```

I tried everything I could find but it keeps giving me other errors

```
    video_port = camera->output[MMAL_CAMERA_VIDEO_PORT];
    still_port = camera->output[MMAL_CAMERA_CAPTURE_PORT];

    //  set up the camera configuration
    {
       MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_CONFIG_T cam_config =
       {
          { MMAL_PARAMETER_CAMERA_CONFIG, sizeof(cam_config) },
          .max_stills_w = state->width,
          .max_stills_h = state->height,
          .stills_yuv422 = 0,
          .one_shot_stills = 0,
          .max_preview_video_w = state->width,
          .max_preview_video_h = state->height,
          .num_preview_video_frames = 3,
          .stills_capture_circular_buffer_height = 0,
          .fast_preview_resume = 0,
          .use_stc_timestamp = MMAL_PARAM_TIMESTAMP_MODE_RESET_STC
       };
       mmal_port_parameter_set(camera->control, &cam_config.hdr);
    }
    // Set the encode format on the video  port
```

Comment: This is a C99 feature and is not available in C++ as written. You would just instantiate your `struct` variable, then assign to the named members afterwards, you cannot initialize using the name members as written.

Comment: @Cyber Does that question explain how to do the equivalent in C++? If not, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: You should not convert working C-code. I suggest wrapping the C-code with C++ (if it has development/maintenance benefits)

Comment: @Barmar No it doesn't, but if they understand what it is doing, they'll know how to do it in C++. Especially since I explained it in the comment following the duplicate link.

Comment: That's quite an assumption from someone who's been here as long as you have :)

Comment: The duplicate does not explain how to do this in C++, reopening.

Comment: @Cyber : But that is neither the only or even the best method of initialising structure members in C++, and comments are not intended for posting answers in any case.  By closing the question down you got your "answer" in in a comment then prevented anyone else from posting an answer in the correct manner

Comment: @DieterLücking : I would say "need not" rather than "should not", but it is a worthwhile point to make that C and C++ are interoperable, and it is often a waste of effort to "convert" C code rather then simply using it as-is, as you risk changing the semantics in ways that are not always obvious.  And of course because C99 has diverged from C++ so it may just be hard work.

Comment: @Cyber: Your suggestion is not a method of *initializing* members at all.  There's a world of difference between initialization and assignment (even in C -- you cannot put those *assignment statements* outside of a function, though that appears not to be an issue in this specific case)

Comment: @Clifford: And then it is a duplicate after all.

Comment: @BenVoigt : It is a duplicate of the question you have identified - it was *not* a duplicate of the [question previously identified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047261/what-does-dot-mean-in-a-struct-initializer) by Cyber as its duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named structure member initialisation in C99 is not implemented in C++.  In C++ you can perform member initialisation using a constructor.  E.g:

```
struct sConfig 
{
    int m_x ;
    int m_y ;

    sConfig( int x, int y ) : m_x(x),
                              m_y(y)
    {}
} ;
```

Or:

```
struct sConfig 
{
    int m_x ;
    int m_y ;

    sConfig( int x, int y )
    {
        m_x = x ;
        m_y = y ;
    }
} ;
```

or even a combination of the two methods.  Then you instantiate an object thus:

```
sConfig myConfig( 10, 20 ) ;
```

Initialising `m_x` and `m_y` to 10 and 20 respectively in this example.

You can then of course only perform the initialisation provided by the structures defined constructors; but that is not necessarily a bad thing - letting the user arbitrarily decide which members to initialise is not particularly safe or maintainable.  You can of course define multiple constructors to perform different initialisations; you would normally want define a default constructor for example:

```
struct sConfig 
{
    int m_x ;
    int m_y ;

    sConfig( int x, int y ) : m_x(x),
                              m_y(y)
    {}

    sConfig( ) : m_x(0),
                 m_y(0)
    {}
} ;
```

So that in this example:

```
sConfig myConfig ;
```

is equivalent to all of the following:

```
sConfig myConfig( 0, 0 ) ;
sConfig myConfig = { 0, 0 } ;
sConfig myConfig = {0} ;
```

Comment: Aggregate initialization still works just fine in C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt :  I have not said otherwise (although I edited to clarify - perhaps you are referring ot the pre-edited text?); you answer remains valid - I have chosen not to duplicate it.  I would suggest that C99 has named member initialisation because it does not have constructors, and equally C++ does not have named member initialisation *because* it does have constructors.  I am simply stating this method as the C++ method of selective member initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support named initializers, only positional ones.

You'll have to read the `struct` definition and arrange all the initializers into declaration order.

Any members which weren't being named in the C code were being initialized to zero implicitly.  You may have to make some of them explicit in order to not skip positions.

If this code is from [JVCleave](http://www.jvcref.com/files/PI/documentation/html/struct_m_m_a_l___p_a_r_a_m_e_t_e_r___c_a_m_e_r_a___c_o_n_f_i_g___t.html) then it appears that the members are already in the correct order, you can just comment out the names and it will still work.

Comment: C++ supports named initialisers using a different syntax via constructor initialiser lists.