# need help to identify a Variable in C

Tags: c

```
static const cmdinfo_t quit_cmd = {
.name       = "quit",
.altname    = "q",
.cfunc      = quit_f,
.argmin     = -1,
.argmax     = -1,
.flags      = CMD_FLAG_GLOBAL,
.oneline    = "exit the program",
};
```

Hi there, while I checking some C code examples I find this statement , I cant able understand this

Is it a String(Array) or `struct` or Function or what it is ?
how does it work ? what does it do ?

Some may found this more basic but i really dont know the name or method of this code to google , someone help me out

Thank you

Comment: You could google "different ways of c structure initialization".

Comment: it's structure initialization using struct member names

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37701574/1848654

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not an exact dupe. The other question is about the older GNU syntax.

Comment: I haven't found a duplicate question yet. :-) Just an answer to a different question that was accepted despite not answering the question at all.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8047261/1848654. For some reason it's been marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question, so I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: @melpomene fixed (and reopened the "dupe")

Answer (score 0):

It's a struct initialised using [designated initialisers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)