# Why am I getting an error when using struct in Atmel Studio 7?

Tags: c

I'm using Atmel Studio.

This is my struct:

```
struct button {
    char *button_port;
    uint8_t button_pin;
    uint8_t flagPress;
    uint8_t flagClick;
    uint8_t buttonCount;
    uint8_t time_button;
} button_left, button_right, button_menu;
```

I want to set initial button parameters.
This is not working:

```
button_left.button_port = "PORTD";
```

I'm getting the error

```
Error expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

However, this works:

```
struct button button_left = {"PORTD", 6, 0, 0, 0, 12};
```

How can I use the `struct` in more comfortable way like this:

```
button_left.button_port = "PORTD"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [example] that tries to set `button_left.button_port` but triggers the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does dot (.) mean in a struct initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047261/what-does-dot-mean-in-a-struct-initializer)

Comment: As a side point, you should attach `const` modifier to the `button_port` field since you're assigning a string literal to it.

Answer (score 0):

Initializations of the struct looks a bit different that initializations of the scalars.

```
struct button 
{
    char *button_port;
    uint8_t button_pin;
    uint8_t flagPress;
    uint8_t flagClick;
    uint8_t buttonCount;
    uint8_t time_button;
};

struct button button_left = {"PORTA"};
struct button button_right = {.button_port = "PORTC"};

// these are called compound literals
struct button button_3 = (struct button){.button_port = "PORTC"};
struct button button_4 = (struct button){.button_port = "PORTC"};
```

You need to read about it in the C book. Do not learn C from
examples or YouTube.

Comment: Ok, i got answer.
Structures have to be initialized outside the functions only in this way:
`struct button button_left = {"PORTD", 6, 0, 0, 0, 12};`
This should be used only inside the function:
`button_left.button_port = "PORTD";`