# Struct Declaration: Valid initializer in declaration?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition

I'm declaring a struct in the IDE (Netbeans) like this:

`struct foo {
   size_t var = 1;
}`

And the IDE says its legal. I compile the project (its a static lib..) and the compiler says its legal (does not moan or throw).

Now since I'm just testing the syntax at this point I have to ask someone who might know if this will actually work when I go to declare a struct of this tag in my procedures like this:

`struct foo myfoo;`

So the question is: Is that a valid initalizer? (`size_t var = 1`) or is the compiler just stroking my ego here? I haven't found anything on google or in documentation like this so I'm guessing it doesn't work the way I hope it will.

*edit So me and the Good 'ol boys here @SO figured out that it will compile in a debug configuration but not a release configuration. Who says one head is better than a couple thousand? :D

Comment: see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c

Comment: @TJD Now that was both quick and awesome! Thanks. But I still don't get why GCC and the IDE let it slip without groaning. Just kicked the warnings up full blast... And I can still hear the crickets chirping. lol.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? I just tried with 4.4.3 and I get an error `expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token`

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it myself in release mode versus debug mode. Origianlly I was in debug mode. It won't compile without screaming in release mode.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko to answer YOUR question: GCC 4.7.0 prerelease

Comment: And thanks Klatchko your input led me to the discovery.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the prerelease. You should let the gcc team know.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko I will if you can't get it to compile in debug. Or else its unconfirmed. For all I know that's intended operation.

Comment: "Bugs are just features or side effects"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's allowed. You need to specify the value for the variable, not the struct:

```
struct foo { size_t var; };

struct foo myfoo = { 1 };
```

As for the IDE allowing it, the obvious possibility would be that the code is really a little different, such as:

```
struct foo { static const size_t var = 1; }
```

...*and* the IDE is compiling it as C++ rather than C.

Comment: Whatever is going on its a curious thing. Maybe that's my next question. "Why doesn't this flag a compile warning?"

Comment: @TristonJ.Taylor You dint tell us what was the cause? Were you using a C++ IDE?

Comment: @PavanManjunath C++ compatible in a C project, in a C file Using GCC in "debug mode"

Comment: Ok that did it! Debug configuration was the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: **You cannot initialize inside the struct definition**, so if the compiler is letting you do that there is something strange going on.

To initialize you have to instantiate that struct in a var (or object if that's what you are going for) and initialize that var.

So, for your struct:

```
struct foo {
    size_t var = 1;
}
```

You would initiazlize as:

```
type function_name(...params...) {
    struct foo myFooVar;
    myFooVar.var = 1;
    ....
    return <type>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "There is something strange going on.." DeJa Vu.. lol In other words: My sentiments exactly...

Comment: Can you confirm the bug? `gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20120407 (prerelease)`

Comment: Found it: debug configuration for a project will let that slide, release mode throws the fire of dragons from middle earth.. or something like that.