# Set initial values to fields of a struct in c ?

Tags: c, linux, struct, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c)

I have a global variables in my code **with initial values** , which are :

```
int init = 0;
int flag = FALSE;
sem_t *mutex;
char * ptr1 = NULL;
char * ptr2 = NULL;
int status1 = -10;
int status2 = -10;
int semaphoreFlag = FALSE;
```

Instead , I decided to add a struct :

```
struct PipeShm
{
    int init;
    int flag;
    sem_t *mutex;
    char * ptr1;
    char * ptr2;
    int status1;
    int status2;
    int semaphoreFlag;
};
```

However ,I can't set initial values to the struct's fields , like I did when 
the variables are global variables .

I guess that the usual way would be to have a `void init()` method 
that would set the values of the struct to the requested values ... but I'm looking for something else ... Any way around this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @DCoder's suggested solution, you can also instanciate and initialize a variable with that structure as follow:

```
struct PipeShm
{
    int init;
    int flag;
    sem_t *mutex;
    char * ptr1;
    char * ptr2;
    int status1;
    int status2;
    int semaphoreFlag;
} defaults = {
    .init = 0,
    .flag = 0,
    .mutex = NULL,
    .ptr1 = NULL,
    .ptr2 = NULL,
    .status1 = 0,
    .status2 = 0,
    .semaphoreFlag = 0
};
```