# gcc member initialization in array of struct

Tags: gcc, embedded

how do you initialize only one member of a structure when you create an array of if, and when you are using GCC?, for example:

```
#define UNUSED OxFF
typedef struct inputs{
    uint8_t state;
    uint8_t limit;
    uint8_t value;
} INPUT_TYPE;

//create array but just care that all members .state are UNUSED
INPUT_TYPE Node1[5] ={ Node1.state = UNUSED }
```

The initialization refers to the array bu not to the member of the struct.
Of course a loop could be used, but I don't want to initialize at run-time with an "input_init" function.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for initializing certain members is a C99 feature.
You're close, try this one:

```
#define UNUSED OxFF
typedef struct inputs{
    uint8_t state;
    uint8_t limit;
    uint8_t value;
} INPUT_TYPE;

INPUT_TYPE Node1[5] = {
    {.state = UNUSED},
    {.state = UNUSED},
    {.state = UNUSED},
    {.state = UNUSED},
    {.state = UNUSED}
};
```

See: [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/1175253)

Edit:

As I wasn't clear enough, I edited the answer.

How array initialization work, was answered here: [How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201101/1175253)

Comment: This will only set `Node1[0].state == UNUSED`. The `.state` member for all other elements will be set to zero.

Comment: I found it at last in [link]http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits its a combination of two cases.

Comment: `INPUT_TYPE Node1[5] = { [0 ... 4].state = UNUSED }` It works fine

Answer (score 4):

I found it at last in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits     its a combination of two cases.

`INPUT_TYPE Node1[5] = { [0 ... 4].state = UNUSED }` it is usefull in large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Since `UNUSED` is a non-zero value, you'll need to specify the initializer for each element of the array if that's what you need:

```
INPUT_TYPE Node1[5] = { 
    {.state = UNUSED}, 
    {.state = UNUSED}, 
    {.state = UNUSED}, 
    {.state = UNUSED}, 
    {.state = UNUSED}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a constructor for init:

```
#define UNUSED OxFF
typedef struct inputs{
    uint8_t state;
    uint8_t limit;
    uint8_t value;

   inputs(){state = UNUSED, limit, value;};

} INPUT_TYPE;
```

?