# Initialize a struct with struct types inside

Tags: c, struct

I would like to create a struct Person, which consists of two struct types and a variable inside. How can I initialize and use the struct Person then?

```
struct name{
   char *firstName;
   char *lastName;
} name;

struct address{
   char *street;
   int number;
} address;

struct person{
   struct name fullName;
   struct address fullAddress;
   int age;
} person;
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/608639)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use nested `{}`.

```
struct person
{
   struct name fullName;
   struct address fullAddress;
   int age;
} person = 
{
    {
        "First Name", /* person.fullName.firstName */
        "Last Name",  /* person.fullName.lastName */
    },
    {
        "Street",     /* person.fullAddress.street */
        42            /* person.fullAddress.number */
    },
    42                /* person.age */
};
```

Then you can access to the other members as follow:

```
person.fullName.firstName;
person.fullName.lastName;
person.fullAddress.street;
person.fullAddress.number;
person.age;
```

Answer (score 3):

For a 18-year-old John Doe, living at address, 42

```
struct person{
   struct name fullName;
   struct address fullAddress;
   int age;
} person = {{"John", "Doe"}, {"address", 42}, 18};
```

Comment: can you please review this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756562/namespace-or-packages-in-c-modules