# Initialize struct of struct using the member struct default values

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I want to initialize a large struct containing other structs to a defined default value, similar to this question: [Initialize a struct with struct types inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067620/initialize-a-struct-with-struct-types-inside)

However, in my real case, the struct contains many members, so defining the default value in the suggested way quickly becomes unreadable. Many of my members are of the same type, so I would like to do define a default value for those and use when defining the default value for the larger struct. Example:

```
struct name{
   char *firstName;
   char *lastName;
} name;

struct address{
   char *street;
   int number;
} address;

struct person{
   struct name fullName;
   struct address fullAddress;
   int age;
} person;

struct name default_name = {.firstName = "John", .lastName = "Doe"};
struct address default_address = {.street = "Street", .number = 42};

struct person default_person = {.fullName = default_name, .fullAddress = default_address, .age = 18};
```

The compiler complains at the last line that the default value is not a compile-time constant. How can I define default_person using default_name and default_address in a way the compiler understands?

EDIT:
Example of what the real case looks more like to show the unreadability issue:

```
struct person default_person = 
{
  .fullName    = (struct name){ .firstName = "John", .lastName = "Doe" },
  .fullName    = (struct name){ .firstName = "John", .lastName = "Doe" },
  .fullName    = (struct name){ .firstName = "John", .lastName = "Doe" },
...
  .fullAddress = (struct address){ .street = "Street", .number = 42 },
  .fullAddress = (struct address){ .street = "Street", .number = 42 },
...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place the struct variable declarations outside any function - at *file scope* - then the initializers must be compile-time constants (because such variables have static storage duration).

The easiest solution is to move the struct variables inside a function, because they probably shouldn't be at file scope anyway:

```
int main (void)
{
  struct name ...
}
```

If you need to have the declarations at file scope, you should look into merging them into a single variable with a single initializer list and it will work as well:

```
struct person default_person = 
{
  .fullName    = (struct name){ .firstName = "John", .lastName = "Doe" },
  .fullAddress = (struct address){ .street = "Street", .number = 42 },
};
```

Comment: I unfortunately need to do this at file scope at the moment. Is there any way to increase the readability in the second option? My real case looks more like this: (see edit to question because of formatting)

Comment: @guybrush_threepwood I'm not making any sense of that, do you mean they are arrays?

Comment: No, they are not arrays. Maybe the example is a bit misleading, but I have several types of data in the struct, and some types are reoccuring and thus I want to make the initialization a bit more readable than what it is at the moment.

Comment: @guybrush_threepwood So post the actual code, not fictional nonsense code.