# structure variable doesnot get initialized in c

Tags: c, struct, char, initialization

i am trying to run a program implementing a function with structures in c... which is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct store
    {
    char name[20];
        float price;    
        int quantity;
    };

struct store update (struct store product, float p, int q);

float mul(struct store stock_value);


    main()
{
    int inc_q;
    float inc_p,value;

    struct store item = {"xyz", 10.895 ,10};  //## this is where the problem lies ##


    printf("name    = %s\n price = %d\n quantity = %d\n\n",item.name,item.price,item.quantity);

    printf("enter increment in price(1st) and quantity(2nd) : ");
    scanf("%f %d",&inc_p,&inc_q);

item = update(item,inc_p,inc_q);

    printf("updated values are\n\n");
    printf(" name       = %d\n price      = %d\n quantity    = %d",item.name,item.price,item.quantity);

    value = mul(item);

    printf("\n\n value = %d",value);
}
struct store update(struct store product, float p, int q)
{
    product.price+=p;
    product.quantity+=q;
    return(product);
}    
float mul(struct store stock_value)
{
    return(stock_value.price*stock_value.quantity);
}
```

When i am initializing that ***struct store item = {"xyz",10.895,10} ;***  the values are not being stored by the members i.e. ater this (struct store item) line the members:

1. **item.name** should be **"xyz"**,
2. **item.price** should be **10.895**,
3. **item.quantity** should be **10**;

but **except** the   **item.name=xyz**   other members take a  ***garbage***  value of their own.. i am not able to understand about this behaviour...
i am using devc++ (version 5.4.2 with mingw)...

am i getting the problem because i am using char name[20] as a member of struct store???

some one please help to remove the error in my code.. reply soon

Comment: Post the output you are getting..

Comment: In addition to improper `printf`, consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c

Comment: I didn't know you can assign a struct like that.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Jim: That's an initialization, not an assignment.

Comment: I didn't know you could initialize a struct like that. Arrays, yes...

Comment: Crystal ball: The next question will be why is `printf("\n\n value = %f",value);` printing "108.950005" instead of "108.950000?

Comment: @Jim : well thats a run time initialization for a struct type of variable.. and yup arrays can also be included as a struct member... moreover i did a silly mistake in the program thats why it was showing garbge values...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the `%d` format specifier to print a `float`, which is undefined behavior. You should use `%f` for floats and `%d` for integers. For your code, that should be:

```
printf("name    = %s\n price = %f\n quantity = %d\n\n", 
       item.name, item.price, item.quantity);
```

because `item.price` is a float.

In a later `printf` you are also using `%d` to print the string `item.name`. It should be changed to `%s` instead.

Comment: For those who didn't know, `%f` is the correct format for both `float` and `double` (because `float` arguments to `printf` are promoted to `double`).

Comment: @interjay,, yup..  i did understand it just on 25th august.. thanks for replying...  it was really A silly mistake by the way...

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `item.quantity` will be giving 10. Then change `%d` to `%f` for `item.price` as it is a floating point type variable.