# Dictionary or Object as Argument in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, argument-passing

I am analyzing some Objective-C code and found the following:

`CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, (CGRect){.origin.x = 0.0f, .origin.y = 0.0f, .size.width = _fullWidth, .size.height = height}, partialImg);`

What is the purpose of `{.origin.x = 0.0f, ...}`?
Is this an object being initialized or a dictionary?

thanks!

Comment: This is short struct initialization of CGRect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) syntax of C99, it has nothing to do with Objective C or dictionaries. You use this syntax to initialize "plain" C structures in contexts where calling [`CGRectMake`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake) is not possible - for example, when you initialize a static variable.

Note that in your case you could have used `CGRectMake` as well for a shorter, easier to read, code:

```
CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, _fullWidth, height), partialImg);
```

Comment: So "designated initializer" has completely different meanings in C99 and Objective-C ...

Comment: @MartinR That's a very nice observation! Yes, it has a very different meaning.