# Cannot assign array to struct property

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm just learning C, and I'm having problems with assigning an array to a property (`pulses`).

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct irPulseSet
{
    int pulseCount;
    int pulses[][2];
} irPulseSet;
```

I create a new variable with the `irPulseSet` type that I created above, and define an array:

```
irPulseSet upButton;

upButton.pulseCount = 31;
int upButtonPulses[31][2] = 
{
    { 0 , 120 },
    { 440 , 360 },
    { 440 , 340 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 420 , 380 },
    { 420 , 360 },
    { 400 , 1140 },
    { 420 , 1120 },
    { 420 , 380 },
    { 420 , 1140 },
    { 420 , 1120 },
    { 440 , 340 },
    { 440 , 360 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 420 , 1120 },
    { 400 , 1140 },
    { 420 , 360 },
    { 440 , 340 },
    { 440 , 360 },
    { 440 , 1140 },
    { 440 , 360 },
    { 440 , 340 },
    { 440 , 380 },
    { 420 , 360 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 440 , 1120 },
    { 440 , 27400 },
    { 7160 , 1500 },
    { 0 , 0 }
};
```

I then assign that array to a property in the `irPulseSet` struct.

```
upButton.pulses = upButtonPulses;
```

But when I compile, I get the error:

> invalid use of flexible array member

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the type of the pulses member in the struct to a pointer to a 2d array, before you had a flexible array member which you have allocate dynamically.

```
typedef struct irPulseSet
{
    int pulseCount;
    int (*pulses)[2];  //pointer to a 2d array

} irPulseSet;
```

And to set the member you do the same:

```
upButton.pulses = upButtonPulses;
```

Or a more clever way to initialize the struct

```
irPulseSet upButton = { 31 , upButtonPulses } ;
```

Comment: @LeeDuhem The brackets are unnecessary.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Yes; No; Operator precedence makes them unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right, those parentheses are not necessary. I made another mistakes when I test it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just one other thing: what are the brackets around the `*pulses` for? I know the * is used when declaring a pointer, but not sure about the brackets.

Comment: You would have an array of integer pointers, without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are making an assignment (`=`) to an array-type.
See [self.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171909/3080396)'s answer points in the right direction if you want both the structure and the array to point to the same place in memory. However, if you want a copy of the data, read on.

---

> invalid use of flexible array member

The reason you're getting this error, is that to use a flexible array member, you must allocate the extra space for the array, for example when you `malloc`'d it. Eg.

```
irPulseSet upButton = malloc(sizeof(irPulseSet) + sizeof(upButtonPulses));
memcpy(upButton->pulses, upButtonPulses, sizeof(upButtonPulses));
```

Answer (score 0):

error due to

```
int pulses[][2];
```

you need to define size !! try it once.

Comment: do int pulses[31][2];
and than write a function to copy upButtonPulses[31][2] to int pulses[31][2];
in struct irPulseSet