# Initialize struct without an assignment?

Tags: c, variables, struct, initialization

I could not find an answer to this on the Internet, so here is my question: Can I define a struct instance without assigning it to a local or global variable in C? E.g.:

```c
struct A {
  int b;
}

struct A foo() {
  return struct A { .b = 42 };
}
```

If this is not possible: why?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Txc81n

Comment: https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2013/07/25/designated-initialization-with-pointers-in-c/

Comment: BTW, functions taking no arguments should have `(void)` as the parameters - otherwise a prototype isn't formed, and the compiler will let you call it with arguments (causing undefined behaviour)

Comment: @Matt MCNabb Thanks for the hint, I was definitely not aware of that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes C99 provides compound literals for this (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18a9efc65e96697e)*):

```
return (struct A) {  42 } ;
```

which is covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.2.5` *Compound literals* and says:

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace enclosed list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose
>   value is given by the initializer list.<sup>84)</sup>

and:

> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
>   initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
>   has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
>   the enclosing block.

and provides several examples including:

> EXAMPLE 3 Initializers with designations can be combined with compound literals. Structure objects
>   created using compound literals can be passed to functions without depending on member order:

```
drawline((struct point){.x=1, .y=1}, (struct point){.x=3, .y=4});
```

`gcc` also has a [nice document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals) on this in it's extension section since it supports this feature outside of C99 as well as `clang`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use compound literals in C99 and later.

```
return (struct A) { .b = 42 };
```

You can even point to them:

```
struct A *a = &(struct A) { .b = 42 };
a->b = 43;
```

These literals are "better" than string literals in that they are writable. The compiler may pool them if and only if you include `const` in the literal's type .

Comment: you can also do `return (struct A) { 42 };`.

Comment: Of course; although I figured he wanted to use designated initializers to avoid errors in case `A` had other members added.

Comment: Yep, in that case it is better to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible since C99. That is a compound literal.

Still, yours has the wrong syntax. Use:

```
(struct A){.b=42}
```

or

```
(struct A){42}
```

Though, go for constant literals if it does not matter:

```
(const struct A){.b=42}
```

All constant literals are subject to constant pooling (including string literals which have type `char[]` for historical reasons).
Constant compound literals and compound literals outside any function have static storage duration,
the rest have automatic storage duration (beware returning a pointer, also they must be initialised each time).

In summary, prefer constant literals where possible.