# Initializing a bitfield of an anonymous struct

Tags: c

I'm not sure if this could be compile related, but the compiler I'm using is IAR 7.10.3.

I have a struct like follows:

```
struct A {
  struct {
    uint8_t x:1;
    uint8_t y:2;
    uint8_t z:5;
  } b;
};
```

And initializes it like:

```
struct A a = {
  .b = 0xFF,
};
```

Now when I look at the struct in memory, only the x bit will be set to '1', the rest will be zero.

Is this how it should behave according to the C standard?

Comment: This is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936022/designated-initializers-and-compound-literals-for-struct-in-c) recently asked question.

Comment: @this he is using `IAR`, and bit-field type can be an implementation-defined type.

Comment: @this c99 says `A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed
int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type.` ... note implementation defined type.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour how? Because I am explicitly initializing '.b'. It seems that this is somehow translated to initializing '.b.x'. I'm still curious if this is how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: @NiklasNorin paragraph 17 which I quote covers this case: `causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.`

Comment: By the way your inner struct is not an *anonymous* struct. c11 defines an anonymous struct as an unnamed and untagged inner struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct A a = {
  .b = 0xFF,
};
```

is parsed by your compiler as

```
struct A a = {
  .b = {0xFF},
};
```

which is equivalent to

```
struct A a = {
  .b = {0xFF, 0, 0},
};
```

Use:

```
struct A a = {
  .b = {1, 3, 31},
};
```

to have all the bits of your bit-fields set to `1`. Or use an union with an `uint8_t` and the inner struct and initialize the first member to `0xFF`.