# Questions on compound literals in C

Tags: c

COMPOUND LITERALS:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s{
 int x;
 int y;
};

int main(){
 int j = 5;
 printf("\n &j : %p \n",&j);
 struct s *p = &(struct s){j++};
 printf("\n p : %p &j : %p x : %d y : %d \n",p,&j,p->x,p->y);
 return 0;
}

o/p:
-----
&j : 0x7fff416b74ec 
 p : 0x7fff416b74d0 &j : 0x7fff416b74ec x : 5 y : 0
```

a] Why is p not holding the address of j ?

b] why is j not being typecast to struct s ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between j++ and ++j?

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
struct s *p = &(struct s){j++}; // compiler should raise a warning
```

is incomplete. It should be like

```
struct s *p = &(struct s){.x = j++};
```

or

```
struct s *p = &(struct s){.y = j++};
```

The uninitialized member will be set ti `0` by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936477/2455888).

The reason that `p` doesn't hold the address of `j` is clear that `p` is holding the address of new object (compound literal), not the address of `j` itself.

Comment: Well, there is `1/2` a compound literal. The warning is of the type `warning: missing initializer for field ‘y’ of ‘struct s’`. So the statement `struct s *p = &(struct s){j++};` is treated as a compound literal with partial assignment of `p->x=5` with `p->y defaulting to 0` as I understand it. So the first statement may better read as `There is no complete compound literal in your code.`

Comment: Please revise our answer. You say "*There is no compound literal in your code.*" and you also say: "*...  `p` is holding the address of compound literal*". Decide: "*To be or not to be?*"

Answer (score 1):

a) p not holds the address of j because p point to freshly created structure. 
if you want, that p point to j, you should write:

```
int * p = &j;
```

b) j is int local (stack) variable, so i see no way, how it can be cast into the structure.

@David C. Rankin, i've reformed my answer

Comment: You need to add more than copy/paste from the [**Compound Literals**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) of the gcc manual (or at least give attribution)

Answer (score 0):

for your first question,, p is of struct type and j is of integer type and you have to make the pointer and the variable of same datatype...
like int *p = &j;      //where j is of int type.

Answer (score -1):

j is of integer type(primitive data) and you are trying to convert it into complex datatype(object).. thus, you are trying to do boxing and unboxing.. which are not concepts of c or c++...

Comment: "*... you are trying to convert it into complex datatype ...*" he is not.