# Initializing Malloc'ed structure

Tags: c, malloc, structure

I am trying to initalize a structure using braces, but i am really trying to initalize the structure that is pointed to by a pointer returned from a malloc call.

```
typedef struct foo{
    int x;
    int y;
} foo;

foo bar = {5,6};
```

I understand how to do that, but i need to do it in this context.

```
foo * bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
*bar = {3,4};
```

Comment: `*bar = (foo){ 3, 4};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This was answered in comments, so making it a CW).

You need to cast the right-hand side of the assignment, like so:

```
*bar = (foo) {3,4};
```

As pointed out by @cremno in the comment, this isn't a cast but rather an assignment of a *compound literal*

The relevant section of the C99 standard is: *6.5.2.5 Compound literals* which says:

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name
>   followed by a brace enclosed list of initializers is a compound
>   literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the
>   initializer list

Comment: It may look like a cast operator but it isn't one. The whole thing is a compound literal.

Comment: @cremno So it would seem. Good point. I've updated the answer with a reference to the standard.

Comment: As a notable bonus: any struct members you forgot to include in a compound literal initializer get zero-initialized by default (just like if they were static objects). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936301/9959012

Answer (score 1):

bar is a pointer that holds reference to the malloced foo struct

Use `bar->x=3;bar->y=4`

Comment: I understand how to initialize it like that, I'm looking specifically for brace initialization.

Comment: In that case, `*bar = (foo) {3,4};` should word.  [demo](https://ideone.com/gzbvUA)