# How Linux knows which ioctl function to call?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

Here is the `ioctl` call in user space:

```
int ioctl(int fd, int cmd, ...);
```

As far as I know, when we want to perfrom IO operations, we define our own `ioctl` function with a set of requests (commands), assign our `ioctl` to a [file_operations](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1525) structure like this:

```
struct file_operations fops = {
 .read = device_read,
 .write = device_write,
 .ioctl = device_ioctl, // device_ioctl is our function
 .open = device_open,
 .release = device_release,
};
```

And the `device_ioctl` function is defined differently compared to the user space interface:

```
static long device_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

I think based on the file descriptor, the kernel can get the appropriate file structure and calls the device's `ioctl`.

This is just a guess because I cannot find it the generic function definition where the kernel selects appropriate `ioctl` function based on the file descriptor `fd` passed into the generic `ioctl` interface? There are only 3 `ioctl` definitions I can find, but apparently those are just the devices' definitions, not the kernel: [ioctl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ioctl)

Comment: can please let me know what these dots (**.**) mean here and how it is works as function pointer ? I am curious to know.

Comment: @indranil - [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/608639)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the Linux source code, fs/ioctl.c (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ioctl.c)

There you will see the syscall for ioctl:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl, unsigned int, fd, unsigned int, cmd, unsigned long, arg)
```

This in turns calls do_vfs_ioctl(), which calls vfs_ioctl() which then calls the unlocked_ioctl function defined for that filesystem in the file_operations structure.

This will be your device_ioctl function that you registered.

Comment: why do we need magic number if our driver ioctl will be called using the fd inode linkage anyways

Answer (score 3):

`device_ioctl` is a function pointer. The kernel simply takes `fd` as an index to an array of `struct file_operations` and calls the `.ioctl` of the corresponding element. The kernel never needs to knows what the function itself is which device it refers to.

This is the basis of "Everything is a file", which is Unix's moto.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's a function pointer. But where is the place where the generic `ioctl` in user space implemented to correctly select the function in the array of file_operations?

Comment: @Amumu, it's _not_ in user-space at all. The user-space `ioctl` merely calls the ioctl system call, passing in the parameters. It's the generic `ioctl` in _kernel space_ that looks at the array of `struct file_operations`.

Comment: @Shabaz I refer to the `ioctl` typically used in user application as user-space `ioctl`. Yes I know it selects appropriate `ioctl` in kernel space. But, I wonder where is the generic `ioctl` in kernel space implemented. I searched, and it only gives 3 definitions, and all these 3 definitions are `ioctl` of drivers: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ioctl

Comment: Perhaps looking at [fs/ioctl.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ioctl.c) may get you somewhere! I don't know about user-space ioctl. As far as I knew, they were a kernel-space implementation. If there is such a thing in user-space, you need to search the implementation of `ioctl` in glibc.

Comment: That could be a good hint. I will try to look into glibc. I already looked at `fs/ioctl.c` but still cannot find the exact same definition with the same `ioctl` interface that accepts file descriptor.

Comment: *"This is the basis of "Everything is a file", which is Unix's moto..."* - Yeah, until everything is not and the model breaks down like with serial ports.

Comment: @jww, you can `open()` and `read()`/`write()` to a serial port like normal files. That means a very good deal of any application can be agnostic of the actual underlying "storage" (actual file, sockets, ports etc). That's a very powerful design which certainly outweighs minor nuisances. The fact that I can `echo` into a serial port, with `echo` never even knowing it's dealing with one is truly amazing.

Comment: @Shahbaz why do we need magic number if our driver ioctl will be called using the fd inode linkage anyways

Answer (score 1):

The kernel will know which `ioctl` function to call because of the **file descriptor**.
To be able to call an ioctl() from userspace you will have to open a file to get the `fd`, tipically a /dev/[some_device] whose driver will implement the file_operations struct, as you pointed out.

Comment: why do we need magic number if our driver ioctl will be called using the fd inode linkage anyways

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ioctl` you pass a file descriptor. You got the file descriptor from opening a device file like `/dev/tty0`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 0 Mar  6 10:47 /dev/tty0
$
```

The number `4` here is the device major number which is encoded into the driver module the kernel has to use.

Comment: Do you know where in the kernel code it selects appropriate device `ioctl` based on the fd?