# struct variable initialization

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I tried to initialize struct variable as following:

```
struct Abc{
    char str[10];
};

int main(){
    struct Abc s1;
    s1.str="Hello";  //error
}
```

I can understand this behavior because it is same as

```
char str[10];
str="Hello"; // incompatible types
```

But look at following initializations

```
struct Abc s1={"Hello"};   //This is fine

struct Abc s2={.str="Hello"};  //This is also fine
```

I remember in my graduation, I read lot of text books which said these both initializations are one and same thing (i.e initialing struct variables using { } notation and explicitly using (.) operator are same thing ). But above discussion proves that they are not same.

*My question is what exactly is difference between these initializations?*

Comment: str="Hello"; is assignment, not initialization...

Comment: You may find [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c?rq=1) informational.

Comment: The first two are not initializations. They are assignments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is, these two lines

```
struct Abc s1={"Hello"};   //This is fine
struct Abc s2={.str="Hello"};  //This is also fine
```

are **initialization**, while this

```
s1.str="Hello";
```

is **assignment**. You can initialize a char array to a string literal, but not through assignment.

Comment: what ??s1.str="Hello"; is not initialization??

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar Similar to native types. `int n = 42;` is initialization. And in `int n; n = 42;`, `n` is uninitialized, and then assigned to `42`.

Comment: So Isn't s2={.str="Hello"}; is assignment?

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar No, that is a special form of initialization called ***designated** initialization*.

Comment: ...but remember that you can still *re*-initialize an array when assigning a new value to the containing struct, because structs admit assignment.

Answer (score 3):

This`struct Abc s2={.str="Hello"};` can be called as designated initialization, whereas `struct Abc s1={"Hello"};`general initialization.

Let me explain the advantage of this designated initialization with example.

Assume structure is having variable like  `struct ex{ char *name; int age; char *city; char *country }` . In this if you want initialize only city&country designated initialization can be used. 
But in case of general initialization each members needs to be initialized separately. This this overhead for the programmer&complex also.

Answer (score 2):

The following assignment statements are exactly same (but wrong):

`s1.str="Hello";` & `str = "Hello";`.

The difference is just that first one is a string inside a `struct`.

And by the way, **initialization** means assigning value to a variable at the time of its **definition**.

`struct Abc s1;` declares and defines `s1` so you initialize it here as:

```
struct Abc s1={"Hello"};   //This is fine
struct Abc s2={.str="Hello"};  //This is also fine
```

Doing this

```
struct Abc s1;
s1.str="Hello";
```

is not a **initialization**, it is just **assigning** constant string literal to `str` pointer which is incompatible.