# C Structure initialization (Array of integers and an integer value)

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure

```
#define MAX 10
struct setArray
{
    int item[MAX];
    int count;
};
typedef struct setArray *BitSet;
```

how should I initialize the elements in the structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c)

Comment: Aside: 1) `typedef struct setArray *BitSet;` though legal, is frowned upon in some style guides:  Suggest avoid (exceptions exists) creating typedef of pointers.  Instead `typedef struct setArray BitSet; BitSet *p = malloc(sizeof *p);`  2) `int` for an array size counter is not as portable as `size_t count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
struct setArray s = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, MAX };
```

Or

```
struct setArray s;

for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) s.item[i] = i;
s.count = MAX;
```

Or

```
BitSet p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) p->item[i] = i;
p->count = MAX;
```