# Understanding snippet of code

Tags: c

Im reading a book and there is no online code reference so I don't understand couple of things.
Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* The API to implement */
struct greet_api    {
  int (*say_hello)(char *name);
  int (*say_goodbye)(void);
};
/* Our implementation of the hello function */
int say_hello_fn(char *name)    {
  printf("Hello %s\n", name);
  return 0;
}
/* Our implementation of the goodbye function */
int say_goodbye_fn(void)    {
  printf("Goodbye\n");
  return 0;
}
/* A struct implementing the API */
struct greet_api greet_api =     {
  .say_hello = say_hello_fn,
  .say_goodbye = say_goodbye_fn
};
/* main() doesn't need to know anything about how the
* say_hello/goodbye works, it just knows that it does */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {
  greet_api.say_hello(argv[1]);
  greet_api.say_goodbye();
  printf("%p, %p, %p\n", greet_api.say_hello, say_hello_fn, &say_hello_fn);
  exit(0);
}
```

I have never seen before:

```
 int (*say_hello)(char *name);
 int (*say_goodbye)(void);
```

and:

```
struct greet_api greet_api =    {
  .say_hello = say_hello_fn,
  .say_goodbye = say_goodbye_fn
};
```

I kind a understand what is happening there, but as I stated before I have never seen that before.

Those things are double brackets in first snippet.
Equal sign, dots and function name w/o brackets in second snippet.

If someone could post some good articles or titles of what is that so I can look online it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no online reference for C??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are function pointers ([How do function pointers work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)) and then, the author initializes these two pointers via the designated initializers (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/330867/2411320) answer).

Comment: Not a dot operator :)

Comment: Well thank you ! I had a bit of trouble formatting the links :p

Answer (score 3):

These are respectively [*function pointers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/3233393) and [*designated initializers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). The function names without brackets are just the way you take a function's address to store it in a function pointer (the `&` is facultative in this case).

Comment: Aren't designated initializers a GNU C extension?