# error: expected expression before '{' token|

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
  struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };
main(){
    struct node a,b,c,d;
    struct node *s=&a;

    a={10,&b};
    b={10,&c};
    c={10,&d};
    d={10,NULL};


    do{
        printf("%d %d",(*s).data,(*s).next);

        s=*s.next;
    }while(*s.next!=NULL);

}
```

It is showing error at a={10,&b};Expression syntex error.please help..
thankzz in advance

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c for other great answers.

Comment: The language provides the `->` operator so that you can say `s->next` rather than `(*s).next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize the variable immediately:

```
struct node a={10,NULL};
```

And then assign the address:

```
a.next = &b;
```

Or use a compound literal:

```
a=( struct node ){10,&b};  //must be using at least C99
```

Comment: why we are type casting at the time of initialiation in a=(struct node){10,&b}.please explain in detail...thankzzz

Comment: @RohitGoel This is an assignment, a is already initialized. That is a compound literal, and that is the selected syntax to use it.

Comment: @RohitGoel your query regarding the _cast_ is well explained in the link provided in my asnwer. Please check that.

Answer (score 6):

Initialization of a struct variable using *only* bracket enclosed list is allowed at definition time. use

```
struct node a={10,&b};
```

Otherwise, you've to use a  [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) [on and above `c99`]

```
a=(struct node){10,&b};
```