# Does C have a shorthand way of initialize a struct with malloc and set its fields?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, initialization, malloc

I have a messy block of code like

```
result = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
result->fx = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
result->fx[0]='x'; result->fx[1]='\0';
result->gx = NULL; result->op = NULL; result->hx = NULL;
```

where I initialize an element of type

```
typedef struct node
{
    char * fx; // function
    struct node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    struct node * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

Is there a shorthand way of doing that? In other words, is there a way to do like I would do in C++?

```
result = new node { new char [] {'x','\0'}, NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you want to initialize all fields with 0, you can use `calloc`. And don't typecast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: If `fx` is always going to be malloc'd with the same size then you could make it an array

Comment: Can you clarify whether `'x'` is to be hardcoded, or if this is pseudocode and you want to initialize `fx` with data that's been entered by the user for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own wrapper function:

```
static node *getNewNode(char *fx) {
  node *p = calloc(1, sizeof *p);
  if(p && fx) {
    p->fx = malloc(strlen(fx) + 1);
    if(!p->fx) {
      free(p);
      p = null;
    } else {
      strcpy(p->fx, fx);
    }
  }
  return p;
}
```

Later you can call this as:

```
node *result = getNewNode("x");
if(result) ...
```

Which is more readable and less cluttery.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have two nested mallocs and initialize everything in one go. However I would suggest the following design:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char fx[2], op[2];    // first byte being null indicates not-present
    struct node *gx, *hx;
} node;
```

and then you can more simply write:

```
node *result = malloc( sizeof *result );

if ( !result )
    errorhandling......

// C89
node temp = { "x" };
*result = temp;

// C99
*result = (node){ .fx = "x" };
```

The C99 example uses *compound literals* and *designated initializers* which are in C but not C++. For more discussion see [How to initialize a struct in ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c/).

You don't have to use the designated initializer but it reduces the possibility for error. Any struct members not explicitly initialized will be initialized as if by `0`.

In both cases, the theoretical temporary object will be optimized away, so this solution should not be considered inefficient at all.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `"x"` is a string literal and therefore the final value of `result->fx` pointing to will not be modifiable. This is a limitation to the OP's approach.

Comment: This means you'll create an extra temporary object on the stack though. A better solution would perhaps be to create a `static const node` with everything already in place.

Comment: @Lundin I compiled with `-O1` and there is no temporary object created on the stack. The assembly instruction `movq` is used to place `'x'` directly in the malloc'd space.   Can you show the code for your suggestion? (bearing in mind that OP probably intends `"x"` to be a value obtained at runtime)

Comment: @alk `fx` is a modifiable array which the string literal is copied into. The final result is modifiable.

Comment: If `"x"` is a run-time input then `static` wouldn't be possible and then it doesn't make sense to have such a `const` object. Otherwise, using the type definition in your example: `static const node DEFAULT = { "x", {'\0'}, NULL, NULL }; ... *result = DEFAULT;` Use designated initializers or don't, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah I see, you changed the `struct`'s defintion.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So does this version if you remove `static`. Anyway, the theoretical temporary object on the stack might very well get optimized away anyhow.