# compiling c code with a c++ compiler

Tags: c++, c

I am attempting to use a c code which i did not write myself in tandem with my own c++ code. When I attempt to compile the c code below I get an error. I am unsure what this c code is attempting to accomplish with the .xxx format. I am at a loss any help would be appreciated.

```
const bmpfile_header_t bmp_fh = {
        .filesz = offset + bmp_ih->bmp_bytesz,
        .creator1 = 0,
        .creator2 = 0,
        .bmp_offset = offset
    };
```

throws the error: missing'}' before '.'

Comment: Here is [a nice description][1] of the meaning of the 'dot's in the structure.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-ansi-c

Comment: Do not compile C code with a C++ compiler! These are two different languages which unfortunately share a lot of the **syntax**. However, many semantics are subtle different and may result in unexpected or even undefined behaviour.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: You should compile this code with a C compiler. Use a C++ compiler to compile your C++ code. Then use a linker to link the two results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.field = value` are designated initializers for the fields of the `struct`, i.e., `bmp_fh.bmp_offset` is set to the value `offset`, etc. You could either give values for all fields of the structure (in order) without the designated (`.field`) initializers, or remove the `const` and assign the values afterwards.

Or, unless you specifically wish to port the C code to your C++ compiler, compile the C code with a C compiler and link it to your C++ program. C++ code can call C functions.

Answer (score 0):

These are *designated intializers* C++ does not support them. Use a constructor or remove them and specify the values in the order defined by the struct definition.

Note that `.filesz = offset + bmp_ih->bmp_bytesz` actually looks suspect, as an intializer in C is required to provide constant expressions which can be evaluated at compiler-time. However, gcc for instance allows such for local variables, but there `const` would only make little sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile the C code with a C compiler and link against it. To reference variables and functions you create a header file with declarations for them, surrounded by `extern "C" { }` and include that header in your C++ code.

Please note that C and C++ are, although similar, different languages and should thus be compiled with their respective compilers. The main purpose of the `extern` declaration is to specify a different way to link to the contained declarations.

As C and C++ compilers often are packaged together using the C compiler should not be a problem.