# How to initialize SDL_Color in C?

Tags: c, sdl

I am making a Graphical Client in C with SDL library and I have a problem when I want to set my `SDL_Color` type.

I declare my variable as

```
SDL_Color color;
color = {255, 255, 255};
/* rest of code */
```

then gcc tells me:

> 25:11: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token  color = {0, 0, 0};

I found pretty good answers on C++ cases with some operator overloading but I'm afraid I really don't know how to fix this one in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not assign a value to a structure like this. You can only do this to initialize your structure :

```
SDL_Color color = {255, 255, 255};
```

You can also use a designated initializer:

```
SDL_Color color = {.r = 255, .g = 255, .b = 255};
```

See the [3 ways to initialize a structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)#Struct_initialization).

If you want to change the value of your structure after its declaration, you have to change values member by member:

```
SDL_Color color;
color.r = 255;
color.g = 255;
color.b = 255;
```

Comment: What you can do though is the following: `static inline SDL_Color mk_SDL_Color(int r, int g, int b) { SDL_Color const c = {r,g,b}; return c;}` you can use it like `SDL_color color; color = mk_SDL_Color(255,255,255);`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the expression in braces only at the initialization of the variable, not in an assignment:

Initialization:

```
SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255 };  // By the way, maybe set also color.a
```

Assignment (member by member):

```
SDL_Color color;
color.r = 255;
color.g = 255;
color.b = 255;
color.a = 255;
```

See more information about struct initialization in [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in your case:?

> https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Color