# C program skips first char in string

Tags: c, struct, printf, scanf

Works fine except skips first character in string name. Can anyone explain what I am not seeing?

```
#include "stdio.h"
/*
*BN
*/
int main(void) {
// Disable stdout buffering
//setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

struct data {
  char name[40];
  char street[50];
  char city[30];
  char state[3];
  char zip[6];
  float salary;
};

struct data p = {
scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %f", &p.name, &p.street, &p.city, &p.state, &p.zip, &p.salary)
};

printf(" Name:%s\n Street:%s\n City:%s\n State:%s\n Zipcode:%s\n Salary:%.2f", p.name, p.street, p.city, p.state, p.zip, p.salary);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that's not how you initialize the structure. [Read more about `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), pay close attention to what it returns.

Comment: the struct initialization is not proper. check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards

Comment: I agree it is not how structure is initialized in c. But can somebody please explain why structure is getting initialized properly except the first character?

Comment: If you wonder what happens, it's that the `scanf` function write to all the members of the structure, and then the structure is *actually* initialized by the value that `scanf` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your structure as `struct data p;` then you do the `scanf`.

```
struct data p;
scanf("%s%s%s%s%s%f", &p.name, &p.street, &p.city, &p.state, &p.zip, &p.salary);
```

[You can check some `struct` stuff here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

Comment: That did it thanks!, Ill review proper initialization of structs and further scanf understanding. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have gone wrong way to initialize your structure

Use this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
/*
*BN
*/
int main(void) {
    // Disable stdout buffering
    //setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    struct data {
      char name[40];
      char street[50];
      char city[30];
      char state[3];
      char zip[6];
      float salary;
    };

    struct data p;//Dont Initialize it here!
    printf("Please Enter Name Street City State Zip Salary:");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %f", &p.name, &p.street, &p.city, &p.state, &p.zip, &p.salary);

    printf(" Name:%s\n Street:%s\n City:%s\n State:%s\n Zipcode:%s\n Salary:%.2f\n", p.name, p.street, p.city, p.state, p.zip, p.salary);
    return 0;
}
```