# Line of code within curly braces

Tags: c

I recently came across a line in a method as follows:

```
range_t range = {0, bytes_usage(value), hm->pair_size};
```

What exactly does this mean then, to have curly braces surrounding the snippet of code?

Comment: its an initalizer, ie setting the value of someting more complex that a simple value type , like int. range_t is probably a struct

Comment: @pm100 oh okay! Is there an alternate way to write this?

Comment: try reading a manual, look for 'initializing structs'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The struct you use is undefined but obviously has *at least* three members, which are initialised within the braces (curly brackets).

```
range_t range = {0, bytes_usage(12), hm->pair_size};
```

The first is hard coded `0`. The second is the result of a function call. The third is the value of a member of another `struct`, which needs a `struct` pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {                // a struct with 3 members
    int a, b, c;
} range_t;

typedef struct {                // a struct that will be used to initialise another
    int pair_size;
} hm_type;

int bytes_usage(int v)          // a function that returns a value
{   
    return v + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    hm_type hh = {42};          // a struct with data we need
    hm_type *hm = &hh;          // pointer to that struct (to satisfy your question)
    range_t range = {0, bytes_usage(12), hm->pair_size};    // your question
    printf("%d %d %d\n", range.a, range.b, range.c);        // then print them
}
```

Program output:

```
0 13 42
```

Comment: `typedef int range_t[3];`?

Answer (score 0):

It's an initializer. It's initializing `range`, which is a type of `range_t`, which is probably a struct. See this question for some examples:

[How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards)