# PLC-ST: How to initialize a structure in declaration?

Tags: data-structures, plc, st

According to the PLCOpen, IEC-61131 standard, is it possible to initialize a structure in the declaration?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of [this C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/1127976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c++ example you gave is where they are defining a `struct` in a function.  The equivalent component in `IEC61131` would be a `function block`.  You can initialize a `struct` in a function block

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK SampleFunctionBlock
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR
    internalBlockStruct:SampleStruct:=(One:=1,Two:=2,Three:=3);
END_VAR
```

and then use this `struct` in the function block code.  You can also initialize a `struct` in a `pou` if you wanted to by following the same syntax.

for reference this is my struct

`TYPE SampleStruct :
   STRUCT
    One:INT;
    Two:INT;
    Three:INT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE`

note: the example I gave is using Codesys syntax.  Most IEC61131 languages have very similiar syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can add default values to structure variables at struct declaration. You can also initialize variables with different values at variable declaration.

```
TYPE ST_Test :
STRUCT
    One     : INT   := 123;
    Two     : REAL  := 4567.5;
    Three   : STRING := 'Hello';
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

In some block:

```
VAR
    //Original default values
    TestOriginalValues  : ST_Test;
    //Own initialization values
    TestOtherValues     : ST_Test := (One:=555, Two:=678.5, Three:='Whats up');
END_VAR
```