# What is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, typedef, in-class-initialization

I need some help understanding where this error is occurring:

> warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

This is the section of the code that it is coming from:

```
typedef struct Hand {
    bool straight = false;
    bool flush = false;
    bool four = false;
    bool three = false;
    int pairs = 0;
    } Hand;
```

Comment: remove the initializers ,, all the `= false;` and `= 0;` This is just a definition of `struct Hand`, you'll need to initialize the fields when you have an instance of `struct Hand`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards)

Answer (score 42):

That's not an error, it's a warning. It tells you that you're only allowed to initialize non-static members of a struct / class starting with the C++11 standard (so called because it was published in 2011). Before that, you weren't officially allowed to by C++98 (published, you've guessed it, in 1998). Long story short, what you're doing has only become legal, official C++ in 2011. Your compiler's default seems to be the 1998 standard.

Try compiling with `-std=c++11` as a command line flag (assuming you're using GCC or clang), and the warning should go away. If you're using a different compiler, there should be a flag for that as well (if it's recent enough to implement C++11).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Code Runner` extension in VS Code, you have to config the `Code-runner: Executor Map`. Add `-std=c++17` in `"code-runner.executorMap"`

As @Răzvan Cojocaru has detailed above, `-std=c++11` works, but I want to use the latestest version.

[image: code runner extionsion]

[image: code runner extionsion]

[image: add -std=c++17]