# I want to print all elements of an array using loop in easy way in C++ but get an error

Tags: c++, loops

**Here is the code:**

```
int myarray[3] = {10,20,30};
  for (int elem : myarray)
    cout << elem << '\n';
```

**if I compile like this:**

```
g++ test.cpp
```

**I get an error**

```
test.cpp:12:17: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  for (int elem : myarray)
                ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: This gave me no issues under C++11 and -Wall flag. You are not correctly using C++11.

`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program`

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291142/what-is-a-c11-extension-wc11-extensions/45291997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291142/what-is-a-c11-extension-wc11-extensions/45291997)

Comment: It's time to update your compiler.

Comment: It's `-std=c++11` for C++11 support, not `-Wc++11`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program
```

You are still not properly compiling under C++11.

Answer (score -2):

so add '-std=c++11' to your compiler command line arguments

Comment: Adding `-Wc++11` will not fix the problem.

Comment: The correct option should be `-std=c++11` or better yet upgrade to a newer compiler where the default is c++11 or greater.