# Initializing function pointers in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct foo{
    void (*del)(void *toDel);
    char* (*p)(void *tp)
} Foo;

Foo init(char* (*print)(void*),void (*delFunc)(void*));
```

Trying to figure out how to assign or initialize the supplied parameters to the struct function pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo init(char* (*print)(void *toBePrinted),void (*delFunc)(void *toBeDeleted))
{
    return Foo{ .del = delFunc, .p = print};
}
```

What about this? Long form:

```
Foo init(char* (*print)(void *toBePrinted),void (*delFunc)(void *toBeDeleted))
{
    Foo tmp = {
        .del = delFunc,
        .p = print
    };
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: did you mean .del = delFunc .p = print ?

Comment: @waffles Yes, exactly, sorry

Comment: is that a C99 or C11 standard notation?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Yes it is local, but as the return type of the function is `Foo`, the `tmp` variable would be copied to the caller. If, for example, caller executes `Foo ptrs_to_fncs = init(ptr1, ptr2);`, where `ptr1` and `ptr2` are appropriate pointers to functions, then the `tmp` will be copied to the `ptrs_to_fncs` and therefore no UB. Returning structs in C works similar to returning objects in C++ - they get copied. Of course, the function `init()` can be rewritten to use dynamically allocated memory instead.

Comment: @iBug These are **designated initializers**, introduced to C with the C99 standard, but i. e. with GCC, they can even be used in C89 and C++ as compiler extensions (even though some limitations might apply).

Comment: Instead of returning a struct, you can pass a pointer to the struct as a function parameter. This avoids additional copying.

Comment: @SBS Yes. Here I expect compilers to inline the `Foo init(...)` function, or at least elide the copy.

Answer (score 2):

[How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards)

You can do it the usual way:

```
Return (Foo){.del=delFunc, .p=print};
```

Comment: will I need to create a variable type of Foo? i.e Foo foo; foo.del = delFunc

Comment: What is `Return`?

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward (most backward compatible approach) to define `foo` as `Foo` and initialise it is:

```
Foo foo = { /* Mind the order of the following initialisers!  */
  delFunc,
  print
};
```