# how can i initialize a string for my person structure

Tags: c, string, struct

I want to create a struct member haircolour  with the struct variable of brown but when I try to compile I get the error
 "character constatnt too long for its type" and "assignment to expression with array type" I would appreciate any help on how to sort this out.

Ive tried a lot of other option such as putting double quotes around brown but this does not work

```
struct person {
int age;
int weight;
int height;
char haircolour[50];

};

struct person john;

john.age = 27;
john.weight = 80;
john.height = 170;
john.haircolour = 'brown';
printf("Here are the personal details of john: \n\n");
printf("age: %d \n",john.age);
printf("weight: %dkg \n",john.weight);
printf("height: %dcm \n",john.height);
printf("hair colour: %s", john.haircolour);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards

Comment: `strcpy(john.haircolour, "brown");` is a good beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings are written between double quotes.

```
john.haircolour = "brown"; //As you said, you have tried this.
```

The actual issue is that you are trying to copy string using assignment (=) operator. That doesn't work.

To copy, you should use `strcpy` OR `strncpy` (better.) as below.

Please read about [strcpy/strncpy from here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) and use them.