# Is there a way to use fcntl locks in C to lock space after the EOF?

Tags: c, posix, fcntl

I'm writing a C Linux program for college, using low-level file I/O (I have to use fcntl, basically). 
I need to lock 8 bytes past the end of the file, to append some new data. Trying this as below returns an Invalid argument error.

```c
struct flock field_lock;
field_lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
field_lock.l_whence = SEEK_CUR;
field_lock.l_start = 0;
field_lock.l_len = 2 * sizeof(int);
// ...
lseek(stocks_fd, 0, SEEK_END);
// ...
fcntl(stocks_fd, F_SETLKW, &field_lock);
```

Any idea how else I could achieve this, or what I'm doing wrong?

edit 1: https://gist.github.com/limelier/5a7ba8ab166a1f586a3c4feec355b83b 
Entire program with an improvement applied to the EOF locks and writing logic, as recommended in the comments below. Same problem still exists, though, and a sample output has been appended.

Comment: `fcntl(2)` indeed says "Bytes past the end of the file may be locked". Can you provide a more complete example, including how you open the file?

Comment: Have you tried defining your lock relative to `SEEK_END` instead of `SEEK_CUR`?  That would be more explicit, and would also remove the need to actually seek to the end of the file before locking the region.

Comment: What error did you get? Besides, if you want to set `F_WRLCK`, your file descriptor must be open for writing.

Comment: Your approach works for me, both as given (with `SEEK_CUR` and `lseek` to end of file) and with the `SEEK_END` variation I suggested, in conjunction with a medium-sized file of random data.

Comment: Your approach works for me too. Please provide more information, the whole program perhaps. :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this actually makes things much easier.  However, I still can't get the problem to go away.  I have pasted the program here (don't judge my horrid macros, I'm getting to those eventually :p) - https://gist.github.com/limelier/5a7ba8ab166a1f586a3c4feec355b83b
Sorry the program is so long (and bloated by error handling), I can provide a more concise version a little later if it helps.

Comment: ^ the problem can be illustrated by running the program with an empty binary file and an instruction file containing "1 1" as arguments -- the output added to the gist for your convenience.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards

Comment: @jamieguinan thanks for the recommendation! it'll definitely help simplify my code a bit.

Comment: I also commented on your gist. :)