# How do i describe every column of 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, 2d, describe

I have 2D array like :

```
data[10][7] = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, *and so on*}
```

So how do i describe every columns as different variable?
for example every first column for both row as variable a, second column for both row as variable b, and so on?

Comment: The thing you are looking for is named a struct, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards

Comment: Study _union type punning_.