# Error initializing nested struct containing array of struct and function pointer c99 and gnu99

Tags: arrays, c, struct, function-pointers, c99

I am getting error during initialization of nested structure containing two members

- `unsigned int`
- `typedef void (*vfptr)(void);`.

The first structure or parent structure contains simply two variables as shown:

```
typedef struct Stype1 {
    unsigned int uiVar;
    vfptr  vfptr1;
}Stype1;
```

The second structure contains above structure as array of struct:

```
typedef struct Stype2 {
    Stype1  Stype1inst[4];
}Stype2;
```

Whenever I try to compile using `gcc 12.2.1` I get error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
   30 |     Stype2inst.Stype1inst[4] = {{1,(vfptr)Vfun1},
```

I also tried initializing the structures using designated initializes as mentioned here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/330867/2805824
- [How to initialize a struct in accordance with C programming language standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330793/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-accordance-with-c-programming-language-standards)

```
typedef struct Stype2 {
    Stype1  Stype1inst[] = {
        {.uiVar = 1 , .vfptr1 = Vfun1 }
        };
}Stype2;
```

But I get error:

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
   24 |     Stype1  Stype1inst[] = {
      |
```

Also tried compiling with `-std=gnu99` and `-std=c99` without any luck.

The entire code is pasted below:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef void (*vfptr)(void);

void Vfun1(){};
void Vfun2(){};
void Vfun3(){};
void Vfun4(){};

typedef struct{
    unsigned int uiVar;
    vfptr  vfptr1;
}Stype1;

typedef struct{
    Stype1  Stype1inst[4];
}Stype2;


Stype2 Stype2inst;

int main()
{
    Stype2inst.Stype1inst[4] = {{1,(vfptr)Vfun1},
                                {2,(vfptr)Vfun2},
                                {3,(vfptr)Vfun3},
                                {4,(vfptr)Vfun4}};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only initialise a thing when you declare it. Your declaration is here `Stype2 Stype2inst;` so the initialisation should also be at that same place. `Stype2inst.Stype1inst[4] = ...` tries to assign to the element 4 of Stype2inst.Stype1inst, but there is no such index (the valid indices are 0, 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: @n.m. As you suggested `Stype2 Stype2inst = {1,(vfptr)Vfun1, 2,(vfptr)Vfun2, 3,(vfptr)Vfun3, 4,(vfptr)Vfun4};` this init worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures and arrays can only be initialised at the point of their declaration. In your case, `Stype2inst` is declared as a structure, so the declaration-with-initialization will be of the form:

```c
Stype2 Stype2inst = { ... };
```

Here, the `...` will be the initial value(s) of the structure's data. That data is an array (with four elements), so we can now 'expand' the form to the following:

```c
Stype2 Stype2inst = { { e0, e1, e2, e3 } };
```

Each of the elements (`e0` thru `e3`) will itself be a structure (of type `Stype1`, and will take the form that you have correctly used: `{1,(vfptr)Vfun1}` (although the cast here is unnecessary).

Putting all this together and adding line-breaks, spaces and indentation for easy reading, we get the following declaration/initialisation:

```c
Stype2 Stype2inst = {   // Outer braces are for the "Stype2" structure
    {                   // Next are for the enclosed array of "Stype1"
        { 1, Vfun1 },   // Each of these is for one element/structure;
        { 2, Vfun2 },   
        { 3, Vfun3 },   // Note that you don't need the casts to vfptr
        { 4, Vfun4 }
    }
};
```

Note: Although the much shorter form of initialisation, which you have 'tried' in the comments to the question (and shown below), is valid, it is unclear and *potentially* ambiguous:

```c
Stype2 Stype2inst = { 1,(vfptr)Vfun1, 2,(vfptr)Vfun2, 3,(vfptr)Vfun3, 4,(vfptr)Vfun4 };
```

Using this syntax, the clang-cl compiler generates the following diagnostic (four times):

> warning : suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces]